# To store and retrieve from sqlite file  ( android programming ) 

Tags: android, eclipse-3.4

I am using **ganymade eclipse 3.4 IDE** and **android sdk** for development . I am trying to store static database file with some values on it in **sqlite** format . How can I add this file into the IDE and fetch the data from that file and store it? Give me the guidance to do the development .

Thanks in advance.

Sivaramakrishnan (frankshiva@gmail.com)

Comment: There have been a number of similar questions asked on this site.. a quick search turned up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Put your SQLite database into your assets directory in eclipse. On first use copy to move it into the "`/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/`" directory.